# open context menu when click on custom listview specific row item

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

i use `base adapter` for populate `listview`, in my `listview row` one `button`.
i want to show `context menu` on `button clicked`. 
**registerForContextMenu()** method is not working in `adapter` and also **OnCreateContextMenu()** also not working in this class.

I have search on Google and did not find a solution.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can launch your context menu using dialog.

Comment: Yes, as context menu is for long clicks.